# SourceTree 1.6.14 cannot find Git 2.4.0 installation on Windows

Tags: windows, git, atlassian-sourcetree

After installing Git 2.4.0 on my Windows 7 system, I tried to change the option in SourceTree 1.6.14 to "Use System Git", rather than the embedded version.

However, upon clicking "Use System Git", nothing happened and the setting remained set to "Use Embedded Git".

How can I make SourceTree use the installed version of Git?

Comment: [The current Windows build](https://msysgit.github.io/) is 1.9.5. I don't know where you got your 2.4.0 from (maybe you compiled it manually), but at any rate, it would probably be better if whoever provided that version (again, possibly yourself) makes sure it installs just like the official Windows versions.

Comment: @hvd Good point, will have a search in the open issue list. I obtained 2.4.0 from here https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be probably fixed in a future patch for SourceTree, however, until it does there is a workaround as follows.

Git versions prior to 2.0 stored `git.exe` in a subdirectory called `bin` and this is what SourceTree is looking for. As of Git >=2.0, `git.exe` moved into a folder named `cmd`.

Therefore, the easiest way to get SourceTree to recognise your Git installation, is to create a symbolic link for the folder using `mklink` as follows:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\>mklink /D bin cmd
```

**Edit:**
Whilst the above fixes Git for the normal GUI operations (commit/push etc.) it does not fix the "Terminal" button, as this command tries to execute `sh.exe` via the following command and fails as `sh.exe` has also been moved in Git 2.4.

`"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i`

**Edit 2**: Further reading - this was raised as an issue by the Git for Windows maintainers [here](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/152).

Comment: Wow, you answered your own question the second it was asked!

Comment: @Hexaholic, self-answering is encouraged. It is [even possible to submit a question and answer at the same time](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @Chris I know that and my comment was not supposed to sound negative - I was just surprised to find an answer here before I even finished to read the question.

Comment: @i_saw_drones does your Terminal button in Sourcetree work after doing this? I can get it to read the new Git, but the Terminal button doesn't work (opens and closes).

Comment: This is fixed in the latest Sourcetree beta (https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/update/WindowsReleaseNotes_public_beta.html): "SRCTREEDEV-108 Support v2.x, 32-bit or 64-bit of Git for Windows as a System Git. NB. requires use of putty/pageant rather than ssh-agent.exe unless running as administrator."